# Excel - Display only max value from multiple criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

Need help with an Excel function to display only the high scorer in the High Score column. Example Adam is best Golf and John is best in Tennis

| Player | Game | Score | High Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Golf | 99.00 | Adam |
| Bill | Golf | 85.00 |  |
| John | Golf | 73.00 |  |
| Adam | Tennis | 25.00 |  |
| Bill | Tennis | 54.00 |  |
| John | Tennis | 79.00 | John |

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Your question is well asked, except that you did not provide any details on what you have tried so far. Usually it is easier for all of us to correct a single error than to think one's way into your specific problem. By asking more specific questions, you are more likely to get satisfying answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one has MAXIFS we can get the max value by Game:

```
MAXIFS(C:C,B:B,B2)
```

Then we use an IF to see if the value is the same as the MAXIFS return, If so we return the name, if not an empty string:

```
=IF(C2=MAXIFS(C:C,B:B,B2),A2,"")
```

[image]

If one does not have MAXIFS, that part can be replaced with AGGREGATE:

```
AGGREGATE(14,7,$C$2:$C$7/($B$2:$B$7=B2),1)
```

Which will use the LARGE function and ignore any errors, which we force by dividing by FALSE when the Games do not match.

```
=IF(C2=AGGREGATE(14,7,$C$2:$C$7/($B$2:$B$7=B2),1),A2,"")
```

Comment: You are awesome Scott!! Definitely a master at this function. I do not have the version of Excel that has MAXIFS but AGGREGATE worked perfectly. Kudos again to your super brain!

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: Done - thanks again

Comment: Hi - one more request: could you build in some error handling so that if all three players are zero score in their game, the High Score column is blank? The current algorithm populates all fields in this condition     thanks again   -Chuck